# C# Attribute.isDefined() example?

Tags: c#, metadata

**Can someone please give me an example of using Attribute.isDefined() to check if a particular custom attribute has been applied to a given class?**

I've checked msdn, but only see possiblities for attributes applied to assemblies, members etc. I'm also open to alternative methods for achieving the same thing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

[Foo]
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ok = Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(Program), typeof(FooAttribute));
        Debug.Assert(ok);
    }
}

class FooAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Comment: That's checking a member - what about an attribute on a class? Perhaps the same works?

Comment: It is *very* unintuitive, the Type class inherits MemberInfo.  So the IsDefined(MemberInfo, Type) overload gets the job done.  Code snippet updated.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>There doesn't seem to be an overload of `Attribute.IsDefined` that takes a `Type`.</strike>

Instead, You can call [`Type.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx):

```
if (typeof(SomeClass).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).Length > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why there isn't an overload?  I wish working with attributes was a bit cleaner.  It's tempting to use marker interfaces and (SomeClass is SomeMarkerInterface).

Comment: There *is* an overload, IsDefined(MemberInfo, Type) gets the job done.  Surprised the heck out of me too :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Type` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) inherits [`MemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx).
Therefore, you can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130869.aspx) that takes a `MemberInfo`:

```
if (Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(SomeClass), typeof(SomeAttribute))
```